# como puedo aumentar la memoria /dev/nvme0n1p5 - Linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, manejo-de-memoria

me estoy quedando corto en memoría resulta que le metí 50GB a la / para instalar programas cuando formatee el pc y al /home le metí como 160GB..... quería saber si puedo aumentar esos 50GB sin necesidad de formatear el pc, no quiero perder la data que ya tengo, ya tengo el 91% de uso en **/dev/nvme0n1p5**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es posible redimensionar ese tamaño? agradezco cualquier ayuda estimados

Comment: Intenta con GParted que es una herramienta con interfaz gráfica. Asegúrate de ejecutarlo con privilegios elevados. Creo que es capaz de redimensionar y mover particiones.

Comment: voy mirar si esa herramienta me sirve para redimensionar el tamaño de disco porque la desconozco, gracias Mateo cualquier cosa te cuento por acá bro